# What is the best way to design fact table from relational DB in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas, business-intelligence, cube

I am designing a data warehouse DB in SQL Server 2012 which will be used to create a cube. Lets say I have 3 tables in the original relational DB

```
Supplier (SupplierId, SupplierName .....)
Invoice (InvoiceId, SupplierId, InvoiceCode, InvoiceName, InvoiceTotal ...)
InvoiceLineItem (InvoiceLineItemId, Description, InvoiceId, Rate, Count, Total)
```

I want to convert this into warehouse database. So I created 3 dimensions and 2 fact tables

```
DimSupplier (SupplierId, SupplierName .....)
DimInvoice (InvoiceId, InvoiceCode, InvoiceName ....)
FactInvoice (InviceId, SupplierId, InvoiceTotal)
DimInvoiceLineItem (InvoiceLineItemId, Description)
FactInvoiceLineItem (InvoiceLineItemId, InvoiceId, SupplierId, Rate, Count, Total)
```

My problem is that I am not sure what is the best approach with foreign keys. Should I move SupplierId key from **FactInvoice** and **FactInvoiceLineItem** into **DimInvoice** and **DimInvoiceLineItem** respectively, so then fact can figure out this info from looking at the **DimInvoice** or **DimInvoiceLineItem**. What is the best approach here. I know it is best to keep it as flat as possible. Any help here as I am quite new to data analysis?

Comment: What event or process are you hoping to analyze?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you need the `FactInvoice` table at all. The only thing it offers is `InvoiceTotal`, and that should be the sum of `FactInvoiceLineItem.Total`. Omitting this table would make the structure rather simple: Just one fact table and three dimensions.

As an aside: I do not see any date dimension. It may make sense to extract this as a separate dimension from where it is currently, probably `DimInvoice`. You would probably want to add "date group fields" like "month", "quarter", "year", depending on user request also "day of week", "week number in year", etc.

Comment: I do have Date Dimension and my FactInvoice has more measures in it, what I am showing here is just a small subset of my cube. I am just interested to know best practices of setting up dimensions and facts especially referenced dimensions. Is it better to nest it or reference it directly from fact table?

Comment: @fenix2222 I tend to avoid referenced dimensions, just in order to keep the model simpler. But there would be other aspects as well: Most client tools display the hierarchies grouped by dimensions. Where would users expect to find the attributes/hierarchies? And there would be a performance benefit (but query runtime increase): in case only the referenced dimension changes, there is no need to re-process the fact data. But actually, I would not expect this specific situation (referenced dimension change, but rest of data not to change) to happen very often.